# Why does subtracting NOW with DATE column give nonsense numbers?

Tags: sql, mysql, date, sql-date-functions

[image: Picture of Problem]

Hello everyone,
i have a problem with the subtracting a DATETIME column with todays DATETIME.
One of the columns has the `HireDate` (Date of hiring a certain employee). I want to know how many Years they are employed.

Thank you in advance!

I tried:

```
SELECT LastName, HireDate, DATE('now'), DATE('now' - HireDate)
FROM employees
```

or

```
SELECT LastName, HireDate, DATE('now'), DATE(DATE('now' - HireDate)
FROM employees
```

I expected: The diffrence, so the time they were hired at the company
I got: negative numbers...

Comment: Please add the tag for the dbms you use

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATETIME, NOW and DATE() are all non-standard.)

Comment: @jens @ jarlh forgot that my bad

Comment: Have a look at [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff). A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+subtract+dates&oq=mysql+subtract+dates) offers plenty of related articles.

Comment: @user1191247 i think that only works with two destinct dates at a time and not the whole column

Comment: [A little further down the page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) I previously suggested - `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2002-08-14', CURRENT_DATE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE(DATE('now' - HireDate)` is not valid, nor is it the way to calculate the difference in years. Instead use `timestampdiff()`

```
SELECT
  LastName
, HireDate
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, HireDate, now() )
FROM employees
```

See it working at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d91ef/1)

Similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112558/mysql-how-to-make-a-datediff-in-years